# Scroll prevent when Modal is open

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a modal on my react app, but I'm struggling to deactivate the overflow when the modal is active. I'm using the following logic:

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './Modal.css';
import BackDrop from '../Backdrop/Backdrop';

class Modal extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.props.show) {
            document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return (
            nextProps.show !== this.props.show ||
            nextProps.children !== this.props.children
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BackDrop show={this.props.show} clicked={this.props.clicked} />
                <div
                    className={
                        this.props.singleItemOptions ? classes.ItemOptions : classes.Modal
                    }
                    style={{
                        transform: this.props.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                        opacity: this.props.show ? '1' : '0',
                    }}
                >
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Modal;
```

I inspected the DOM tree and when the modal is active the style property appears in the body element tag. Not sure what could be the issue. I was expecting this to work because other people use it. Could this be related to other CSS styles on my app?